# Very slow query

Tags: query, get-posts, performance

This query works, but it takes upwards of 20 seconds to run on a Quad Core dedicated server... How can I optimize this?

```
$slides=get_posts(
    array('post_type' => 'any', 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'desc', "tax_query" =>
        array(
                "relation" => "OR",
                 array(
                    "field" => "id",
                    "terms" => array(36),
                    "taxonomy" => "category",
                    "operator" => "IN"
                ),
                array(
                    "field" => "id",
                    "terms" => array(36),
                    "taxonomy" => "music-categories",
                    "operator" => "IN"
                ),
                array(
                    "field" => "id",
                    "terms" => array(36),
                    "taxonomy" => "video-categories",
                    "operator" => "IN"
                ),
                array(
                    "field" => "id",
                    "terms" => array(36),
                    "taxonomy" => "mixtape-categories",
                    "operator" => "IN"
            )
            )
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use explicit post types, i.e. `'post_type' => array('post','music'...)`. Right now your query check revisions and attachments as well and they are probably half of the post in your DB.
2. From your code it looks like you should know in advance which taxonomy is relevant to your query (it is unlikely that a term number 36 has relevant meaning in all 4 taxonomies). You should query for only the relevant taxonomies.
3. If you just need the 5 most recent published posts, then maybe you should calculate it on the fly when new posts are added, avoiding the use of the query.

   ```
   add_action('publich_post','my77483_change_cache');
   function my77483_change_cache($post_id,$post) {
     if (not meeting criteria)
       return;
     $chached = get_option('my77483_query_cache');
     if (count($cached) == 5) 
       array_shift($cached); // remove the oldest post. 
     $cached[] = $post_id;
     update_option('my77483_query_cache',$cached);
   }
   ```

This way your query becomes

```
$chached = get_option('my77483_query_cache');
$posts = get_posts('post__in' => $cached);
```

The only problem is what to do in delete, then maybe you should run you original query, but that should be a very rare event.

Comment: in fact term 36 is in all of those taxonomies. it is the same term but tax_query doesnt allow searching "any" taxonomy for a term... and adding the array of post types did not change anything for the query time.

Comment: can you explain what the query supposed to find?

Comment: basically i have a term called "show in slideshow" in each of 4 post types. the post types each have their own taxonomies. this slides query is trying to find the latest posts with the "show in slideshow" term

Comment: Then maybe you should use costume field for that? I think a look up in the meta data should be much faster then a look up in 4 different taxonomies.

Comment: my writers would never figure that out if i did that. i suppose i could somehow disguise a custom field for it on save_post action. will consider it thanks

Comment: added a caching based suggestion

Comment: actually im already caching it but it still takes 20 seconds to save posts `update_option('homeslider_vals',json_encode($slides));`

Comment: i most likely will do the post meta thing on save_post action, but i was just wondering if there was a known thing i could do to fix the query.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the query itself is slow or anything else slows it down, try running your query directly in the database, and have a look at how long it takes there.

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>
```

This shows you the latest Query that WordPress ran in your database.

If the query is really slow in the database, try caching the results, running this specific quer only once every hour or so. I usually do this with menus - but it works with anything. Using transients to save the output HTML.

I wrote about this technique [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77375/15680).

If you need different output for different taxonomies, try adding the TermID in the name of the transient.

You could delete the transients either on 'update_post' or let them expire after a certain time.